# How to partition 128 MB space on El Capitan?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, disk-utility, partition, ssd

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu with El Captain MacBook Pro mid 2012 following this guide: [How to Dual-Boot OS X and Ubuntu](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs171/materials/pdfs/How_to_Dual-Boot_OSX_and_Ubuntu.pdf)

I want to partition a 128 MB space called Ubuntu Boot Loader along side my main partition but, when using Disk Utility, this task seems impossible. It will create another untitled partition (half the size of my drive (128 GB)) and then when I hit accept it will only create that Untitled 128 GB partition (but name it Ubuntu Boot Loader) and it will fail on creating my 128 MB partition. I have no idea how to simply make a small partition, is there an easier way to do it on Mac without dealing with all the BS introduced by Disk Utility? Can provide pics of whats happening if needed.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1639530?tstart=0) seems to explain it pretty well. Though HFS+ is [well within the bounds of creating a partition that size](http://ntfs.com/hfs.htm), Disk Utility attempts to prevent you from creating any partition under 10% of the size of your disk. You'll want to use [diskutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html) from the command line instead. Take a look at `partitionDisk`, `resizeVolume`, and `splitPartition` to determine which one is right for you.

Comment: having difficulty using any of these commands on my main drive

Comment: @user3470987 You may have to reboot into your recovery partition to be able to use them (or even onto an external drive or Internet Recovery depending) as many commands that interact with your main disk/partition won't work when you're booted to it.

Comment: On problem with Nailen Matschke's instructions is that he uses the `bless` command without disabling "System Integrity Protection" (SIP). Clearly, some steps have been omitted from his instructions. Another thing, Part 4 was the preferred way of booting, but with El Capitan one is better off using the a FAT32 formatted EFI partition to boot. This is way operating systems were meant to boot in an EFI scheme.